# css: how to sticky a DOM's position to another DOM that has absolute position in responsive design?

Tags: css, dom

HTML:

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.parent{
  width : 50vh;
  height : 50vh;
  position : relative; 

} 
.b{
   top: 15vh;
   position: absolute;
   margin-left: 15vh;
}
```

The issue is, I want to put DOM `.a` at the top center of the `.b`. how should I write the css rule?
[image]
And since it's using `vh` to define the size of the `.parent` and `.b`, and `.a` has a fixed size. if I use `abosulte` position and give `a` a fixed `top` and `left` value, it wont go to the position that I desired.
It has to be pure CSS (or scss). thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close the div's properly. I use a flexbox for the parent. Hope this helps.

```css
.parent {
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
  border: solid thin red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.a,
.b {
  top: 30vh;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.a {
  border: solid thin green;
  width: 20%;
}

.b {
  border: solid thin blue;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class="a">a
  </div>
  <div class="b">b
  </div>
</div>
```